# Do I need to keep the fields for my polymorphic address in the view to make accepts_nested_attributes_for work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem where my classes are posted to the server but not saved and I can't figure out why and would appreciate some help in the matter.

First of all take my account class it has a reference to the address and defines both a billing and a delivery address.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :billing_address, :as => :addressable
  has_one :delivery_address, :as => :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address,
    :allow_destroy  => true,
    :reject_if      => missing_attrs?('street_one', 'zip', 'city', 'country_id')

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :delivery_address,
    :allow_destroy  => true,
    :reject_if      => missing_attrs?('street_one', 'zip', 'city', 'country_id')
end
```

Now my address classes look like follows

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true 

  validates_inclusion_of :type, :in => %w(BillingAddress DeliveryAddress ), :message => "Please speficy either billing or delivery address"
  attr_accessor :street_one, :street_two, :zip, :city, :country_id, :region
end   

class BillingAddress < Address
end

class DeliveryAddress < Address
end
```

Then I have a view with the following form and I must say it does look perfect in the browser, all the fields are there and the names are correc with the array elelments and all.

```
=semantic_form_for [:admin,@account] do |f|          
  = render 'shared/errors', :target => @account
  =f.inputs                         
  =f.semantic_fields_for :billing_address do |address| 
      =address.inputs name:"Billing Address" do
        =address.input :street_one
        =address.input :street_two
        =address.input :city
        =address.input :zip
        =address.input :region
        =address.input :country   

  =f.semantic_fields_for :delivery_address do |address| 
      =address.inputs name:"Delivery Address" do
        =address.input :street_one
        =address.input :street_two
        =address.input :city
        =address.input :zip
        =address.input :region
        =address.input :country                         
  =f.semantic_fields_for :users do |user|                          
    =user.inputs name:"Default user" do
      =user.input :email
      =user.input :password
  =f.submit
```

If I check this with `raise params.to_yaml` it does look correct though the polymorphic fields for addressable and type is missing. I guess since I build this in the controller I need to keep them in the view before I post them back to the controller before update and create. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969025/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-belongs-to-polymorphic/3975758#3975758) but can't figure out exactly what it does.

Can I have your best suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the missing fields in the form and now it's working perfectly!