# RoR - Processing partials from different models within one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to build a model which render/process partials from others models. Basically, a master model would provide some generic features while embedding different models depending on user input.

In other words, within the same model, I need to render "_form.html.erb" from various models and save them as a nested model would do.

I know [nested model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) would do the work if it was always the same type of model.

```
class Master < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :{change depending on user input}
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :{change depending on user input}
end
```

I seen polymorphic models but it seems to do the exact opposite (i.e. one partial in multiple models).

Any ideas? Polymorphic nested model or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely looks like you need a polymorphic association here, but accepts_nested_attributes_for does not support polymorphism.

However, take a look at this related question [accepts_nested_attributes_for with belongs_to polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969025/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-belongs-to-polymorphic)

Maybe in your form you could do something like the following to render the correct _form partial:

```
<%= render :partial => File.join(@master.thing.class.name.underscore.pluralize, "form") %>
```

Good luck!