# accepts_nested_attributes_for + belongs_to does not show fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
  has_many :orders
end
```

and

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

the idea is that if the user is already logged in, I just want to make a order for that user, but if he is not logged in, then I will ask him to register in the same time as making order. 
here is the form for orders

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :quantity %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :quantity %>
  </div>

  <% if current_user %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= current_user.email%>
  </div>
  <%else%>
    <%= f.fields_for(:user) do |user_form| %>
        <%= render "newuser_fields", :f => user_form %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and new users fields are:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
```

The problem is that it won't show fields for user!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User has many orders so `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will be used in User model.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Nested resources can't be saved if the parent is not present, so you will create the user first and then create its orders.

Usually, if `user` doesn't exist will be redirected to the signup page. If you don't want so you can do something like following on your in your `OrderController#new` action

```
if current_user
  @order=current_user.orders.build
else
  @user=User.new
end
```

And in your order form you can check if user is signin simply create order form if not create user form and then add nested filed for order

```
# app/views/order/_form.html.erb
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  //order form

<% else %>
  // user form 
  <% form_for @user do |uf| %>
    <%= uf.text_filed :email %>
    <%= uf.password_filed :password %>
    //now order fileds
    <%= uf.fields_for :orders do |of| %>
      //porder fileds 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then in `create` action for user and order you have to add appropriate check

Here is a hack showing how you can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `belongs_to`:

[accepts_nested_attributes_for with belongs_to polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969025/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-belongs-to-polymorphic)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could just not use accepts_nested_attributes (and still use fields_for). The user data will then be in params[:user] (or params[:order][:user], or params[:users], not sure, just look in server log, after you remove accepts_nested_attributes because that will change the field name). So you can just create the user manually first in the controller create action:

```
@user = current_user || User.create!(params[:user])
@order = @user.orders.build(params[:order])
```

The extra benefit is that you have a little more control this way and it's only 1 line more.