# Rails - Unable to create polymorphic nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app with three models.  At the highest level is a `JobSpec`

```
class JobSpec < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job_template, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :job_spec
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_template
end
```

This has a polymorphic association with a `job_template`, one of which is a `GooddataExtract` template

```
class GooddataExtract < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :job_spec, as: :job_template, inverse_of: :job_template
  has_many :gooddata_reports, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :gooddata_extract
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gooddata_reports, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

which in turn has a one-to-many relationship with a `GooddataReport`

```
class GooddataReport < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gooddata_extract, inverse_of: :gooddata_report
end
```

I'm having trouble constructing a parameter hash that will create the `GooddataReport` items.  When I use

```
JobSpec.create(job_template_type: 'GooddataExtract', job_template_attributes: { gooddata_pid: 'abcdefg', gooddata_reports_attributes: { '1' => { name: 'george', report_oid: '123456' } } })
```

The `JobSpec` and `GooddataExtract` records get created just fine, but not the `GooddataReport` records.  There are no error messages or anything, they just fail to get created.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!  Unfortunately I didn't provide the full example needed to figure out the issue.  I had forgotten about the `build_job_template` method that was in the `JobSpec` class.  This is way I was getting `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to work with a polymorphic model according to [accepts_nested_attributes_for with belongs_to polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969025/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-belongs-to-polymorphic).  I had introduced a variation on that SO answer that was preventing nested attributes from getting passed down the hierarchy.  After resolving that issue, it's working as expected!

```
class JobSpec < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job_template, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :job_spec
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_template

  def build_job_template(params)
    klass = job_template_type.constantize
    self.job_template = klass.new(params)
  end
end
```

Comment: How and where is `job_template_type` defined and set?