# Rails how to create a new record which has a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Location` model that is polymorphic via `:locatable`

An `Event` has a `Location`:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :location, as: :locatable
end
```

In the `events_controller#create`, how can I create a new Event with the location passed in via params?

```
def create
  property = Event.create! params.require(:event).permit(:name, :time, :location, :organizer_id, attachments: [])
  # ... other stuff, and finally render JSON response
  end
```

However, Event.location is `nil`.  How can I create a location for the Event?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create a new location or just associate existing location with a new event?

Comment: Show your server's log when you do that request. `:location` on the permitted hash references a single value, check this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969025/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-belongs-to-polymorphic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locations` table contains a foreign key called `locatable_id`, which establish polymorphic association to the `events` table.

To create a `location` belonging to a `event`:

events_controller.rb

```
def create
  event = Event.new(event_params)
  location = event.location.build() #or event.location.build(location_parms)
  location.save #will create record in events as well as location associated with the event
end

private
  def event_params
     #Whitelist only events attributes
     params.require(:event).permit(:name, :time, :organizer_id, attachments: [])
  end
```

Comment: It is better to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, if author needs to create a new location together with event

Comment: @Vasilisa Yep, that can be an alternative too . thanks :)

Comment: can you give me an example for that?  I tried it by adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for :location` to my Event model.  In the controller, i per mit `location_attributes: [:street_1, ..etc ]` but location is not created.

Comment: @aperson Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969025/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-belongs-to-polymorphic

Comment: @aperson Also you can look here https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Nested-forms-with-polymorphic-association-in-Active-Admin-Formtastic

Comment: @aperson Here https://forum.upcase.com/t/rails-polymorphic-associations-in-a-nested-form-in-one-html-table/6708